# Ordenação de listas com múltiplos parâmetros utilizando expressão lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, expressões-lambda, classificação

Dado a classe `Ponto`, a função `ordenar` realiza a ordenação dos elementos da lista seguindo o seguinte critério: primeiro valor em `x`, depois `y` e finalmente valor em `z`.

Beleza, o código funciona. Porém gostaria de entender como essa expressão `lambda` é "executada na prática" (o que ela faz por baixo dos panos, digamos). Como pode algo relativamente complexo ser executado em uma única linha de código?

Código completo:

```
import random


class Ponto():
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x) + ' ' + str(self.y) + ' '+str(self.z) 


def cria_pontos(quantos=10):
    lista = []
    for i in range(quantos):
        x = random.randint(0, 100) 
        y = random.randint(0, 100) 
        z = random.randint(0, 100)
        p = Ponto(x=x, y=y, z=z)
        lista.append(p) 
    return lista


def ordernar(lista=None):
    lista.sort(key=lambda p: (p.x, p.y, p.z))


def main():
    pontos = cria_pontos(quantos=5)
    pontos.append(Ponto(x=1,y=2,z=3))
    pontos.append(Ponto(x=2,y=3,z=2))
    pontos.append(Ponto(x=2,y=2,z=2))

    ordernar(lista=pontos)
    for p in pontos:
        print(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Criei essa classe `Ponto` para usar de exemplo para facilitar o entendimento da minha pergunta. Por favor, não se atente a concepção da mesma.

Comment: Muito boa a concepção da classe `Ponto` para ter um exemplo mínimo, simples e completo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `sort`, da classe `list`, quando utilizado com o parâmetro `key` irá executar a ordenação conforme o valor retornado pela expressão definida em `key`, não o valor presente na própria lista. Para o seu caso, usa-se:

```
key=lambda p: (p.x, py. p.z)
```

Ou seja, a expressão que será utilizada será uma expressão lambda que converterá um objeto do tipo `Ponto` em uma tupla com as respectivas coordenadas do ponto. Nativamente, no Python, ao se comparar duas tuplas, a comparação se dá valor a valor, da esquerda para a direita, isto é, compara x, depois y e finalmente z.

Assim, considerando uma lista breve de pontos:

```
lista = [Ponto(x=1,y=2,z=3), Ponto(x=2,y=3,z=2), Ponto(x=2,y=2,z=2)]
```

Quando executado a função de ordenação:

```
lista.sort(key=lambda p: (p.x, p.y, p.z))
```

Grosseiramente falando, o que ocorre é:

1. Define uma lista auxiliar com o primeiro valor da lista: `saida = [Ponto(x=1,y=2,z=3)]`;
2. Pega o segundo valor da lista, itera sobre a lista auxiliar e aplica a expressão lambda tanto no valor a ser adicionado quanto no valor presente na lista auxiliar, comparando seus retornos:

   - O retorno da expressão lambda para o valor a ser adicionado será: `(2, 3, 2)`;
   - Percorre a lista auxiliar e o retorno da expressão para o valor na lista auxiliar será: `(1, 2, 3)`;
   - Compara as duas tuplas retornadas e, como a tupla do valor a ser adicionado estará após à tupla retornada para o valor na lista auxiliar, o valor é inserido após;
   - A lista auxiliar fica, então: `saida = [Ponto(x=1,y=2,z=3), Ponto(x=2,y=3,z=2)]`;
3. Pega o terceiro valor da lista e repete-se o processo:

   - O retorno da expressão lambda do primeiro valor da lista auxiliar será: `(1, 2, 3)`;
   - O retorno da expressão lambda para o valor adicionado será: `(2, 2, 2)`;
   - Comparando-as, verifica-se que o novo valor deve ser adicionado após o primeiro;
   - Então efetua-se a mesma comparação com o segundo valor:
   - O retorno da expressão lambda do segundo valor da lista auxiliar será: `(2, 3, 2)`;
   - Comparando-as, verifica-se que o novo valor deve ser inserido antes do segundo;
   - Assim, o novo valor é inserido na lista auxiliar entre o primeiro e o segundo valor, ficando: `saida = [Ponto(x=1,y=2,z=3), Ponto(x=2,y=2,z=2), Ponto(x=2,y=3,z=2)]`;
4. Terminadas as iterações, o novo valor de lista é definido como a lista auxiliar: `lista = saida`;

Desta forma, após a ordenação, a lista ficaria:

```
lista = [Ponto(x=1,y=2,z=3), Ponto(x=2,y=2,z=2), Ponto(x=2,y=3,z=2)]
```

Ordenado conforme os valores de x, y e z, respectivamente. O desempenho da função não é muito afetado pela utilização do parâmetro `key` porque, devido à implementações internas da linguagem, a expressão definida em `key` é chamada apenas uma vez para cada valor da lista, independente de quantas vezes esse valor é utilizado no processo de ordenação.

Comment: Se quiser saber exatamente o que ocorre *por baixos dos panos*, comenta que eu tento buscar direto no código fonte o que é executado.